<Link> vs <a> for offsite navigation in NextJS
When linking to other pages on a site in NextJS, I know using <Link> is better because it supports prefetching and client-side rendering.
With that said, though, is it better to use <Link> or <a> when navigating to an external page/other URL? Is there any difference?

On their docs, they mention that

Link is a built-in component that extends the HTML a tag to provide prefetching and client-side navigation between routes.

So, it's most likely that Link only prefetches when you are navigating between the routes in your project. But since the Link component extends the a tag, the functionality when navigating to an external page is the same for both. If you want to standardize to a single component to be used for navigation across your project, I recommend using Link.
